# How to capture the exception when Assert get failed either in Nunit or MsTest

Tags: nunit, mstest

How to capture Failed Assert exception message or state when using NUnit ir MeTest Assert method.

I was trying to capture "AssertionException" when my assert get failed, how can i capture that using either NUnit or MsTest. since Assert method doesn't return any type. My requirements are Test should continue even when assert get failed to finish remaining assertions, should capture the error and should fail this assert. I was using below code statement. When i use Nunit framework its failing and continuous to next assert buy not able to capture even when i use try.. catch block where as in MsTest its failing, capturing using try..catch block and not continuing to next assertion.
Much appreciated for any help!

```
    public static void ResponseValueAssert(dynamic actualValue, dynamic expectedValue, string nameOfAssert)
    {
        //var ex = Assert.Throws<AssertionException>(() =>
        //Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, "Actual value doesn't match with Expected value {0}", nameOfAssert));

        if (ResponseValueAssertImplicit(actualValue, expectedValue, nameOfAssert))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Assert:- {0}: <PASS>", nameOfAssert);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Assert:- {0}: <<FAIL>>", nameOfAssert);

            Console.Error.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Assert:- {0}: <<FAIL>>", nameOfAssert);

            // Assert.Fail();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Expected Value: {0}.\r\nActual Value: {1}.", actualValue, expectedValue);
    }

    public static bool ResponseValueAssertImplicit(dynamic actualValue, dynamic expectedValue, string nameOfAssert)
    {
        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, "Actual value doesn't match with Expected value {0}", nameOfAssert);
            return true;
        }
        catch (AssertionException ex)
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not useful to ask a question about two completely different pieces of software as one thing. The answer would obviously be different for NUnit and MSTest, which are implemented quite differently these days.

So I'll answer only with respect to NUnit, since I have no idea what you would do with MSTest anyway.

In NUnit, if you want a test to continue so that more than one assertion can be reported on in the same test, you use multiple assertions. That is...

```cs
Assert.Multiple(() =>
{
    // Put your various asserts here
};
```

NUnit will report all the failed asserts. At the end of the block, the test will be terminated if any of the asserts failed.

Note that many people will say that more than one assert in a test is a bad idea. I believe it is most of the time but that there are situations, like checking multiple properties of the same object, where it can be useful.

Also, for the record, you should **never** be catching exceptions that are used internally by the test framework. They are basically hidden implementation details and all your work can be lost in the next release of the software... as has happened already to some people in this case.